# How can I add a route on top of the dynamic route Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs3

I have a few dynamic routes like this:

```
path: '/group/:id',
name: 'Group',
```

I need to edit the group contents in a separate view, which is not a modal, and pass some data to it. The link should be something like this

... group/3/edit

Child routes seem different. Which concept should I explore to do it?

**PS: I found the solution that seems too simple.**

I just created a separate route:

```
{
    name: 'EditGroup',
    path: '/group/:id/edit',
    component: EditGroup,
    props: true
},
```

And pass the `id` as a prop from task component. Would it be a sound approach?

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
path: 'group/', 
children: [
 {
   path: '',
   name: 'groupView',
},
 {
   path: ':id?/',
   name: 'groupIdView',
},
 {
   path: ':id?/edit',
   name: 'groupIdEdit',
}
]
```

where your first child will be you group view
second will be the id view
and lastly the edit view

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you.
Assuming that you use nested children route.

nested routes
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

path: 'group/',
children: [
{
path: '/group/:id/edit',
name: 'child-group',
props: true,
},
]

you may also use props and pass it to router link as params.

set props to true
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html